# Cleanest way to replace np.array value with np.nan by user defined index

Tags: python, arrays

One question about mask 2-d np.array data.

For example:

1. one 2-d np.array `value` in the shape of 20 x 20.
2. An index `t = [(1,2),(3,4),(5,7),(12,13)]`

How to mask the 2-d array `value` by the (y,x) in `index`?

Usually, replacing with np.nan are based on the specific value like `y[y==7] = np.nan`

On my example, I want to replace the value specific location with *np.nan*.

For now, I can do it by:

1. Creating a new array `value_mask` in the shape of 20 x 20
2. Loop the `value` and testify the location by **(i,j) == t[k]**
3. If True, `value_mask[i,j]`  = `value[i,j]` ; *In verse*, `value_mask[i,j]`  = np.nan

My method was too bulky especially for hugh data(3 levels of loops).
Are there some efficiency method to achieve that?   Any advice would be appreciate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are nearly there.

You can pass arrays of indices to arrays. You probably know this with 1D-arrays.

With a 2D-array you need to pass the array a tuple of lists (one tuple for each axis; one element in the lists (which have to be of equal length) for each array-element you want to chose). You have a list of tuples. So you have just to "transpose" it.

```
t1 = zip(*t)
```

gives you the right shape of your index array; which you can now use as index for any assignment, for example: `value[t1] = np.NaN`

(There are lots of nice explanation of this trick (with `zip` and `*`) in python tutorials, if you don't know it yet.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [np.logical_and](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html)

```
arr = np.zeros((20,20))
```

You can select by `location`, this is just an *example location*.

```
arr[4:8,4:8] = 1
```

You can create a `mask` the same shape as `arr`

```
mask = np.ones((20,20)).astype(bool)
```

Then you can use the `np.logical_and`.

```
mask = np.logical_and(mask, arr == 1)
```

And finally, you can replace the `1`s with the `np.nan`

```
arr[mask] = np.nan
```

Comment: your location is just meant as an example, **but** you can always select only "rectangles" by hardcoding the slices this way, so it won't be general enough...

Comment: @Ilja I use the  `arr[4:8,4:8]` as part of the `np.logical_and` solution I am presenting in my answer to the OP's question. That's what I mean by example.